# How to add two hexadecimal numbers in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to add two hexadecimal variables in a bash script.  I want them to start as hex and end in hex, not decimal.

What I've come up with so far is a bit of a round about hack. Is there a better or more elegant solution?

```
BASE=0xA000

OFFSET=0x1000

NEW_BASE=$(( $BASE + $OFFSET ))

NEW_BASE=`printf "0x%X\n" $NEW_BASE`

echo $NEW_BASE

0xB000
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in `bash`, `printf` is the only builtin way to reformat a number in a different base and only bases 8, 10 and 16 are supported.

In `bash` (contrary  to shells like `ksh93` or `fish`), using command substitution implies forking a subshell. You can use `printf -v` here to avoid the subshell (also available in recent versions of `zsh` for `print` and `printf` (`print -f`) which also supports printing into arrays):

```
printf -v NEWBASE '%#X' "$((BASE + OFFSET))"
```

(in `bash`, contrary to `zsh`, `$((...))` is subject to word splitting, so needs quoted to avoid the dependency on `$IFS`).

In `zsh`, you can specify the expansion base as part of the arithmetic expansion syntax (bases 2 to 36):

```
$ echo $(([#16] 0xff + 0xff))
16#1FE
$ echo $(([##16] 0xff + 0xff))
1FE
$ echo 0x$(([##16] 0xff + 0xff))
0x1FE
$ echo $(([##2] 0xff + 0xff))
111111110
```

With ksh and zsh, you can also force the expansion of an integer variable to be in a specific base with:

```
typeset -i 16 NEWBASE
```

The expansion will be in the `16#1FE` form. ksh93 supports bases up to 64, `zsh` and `mksh` up to 36.

ksh93's `printf`  builtin supports outputting number in arbitrary bases as well with or without the `n#` prefix:

```
$ printf '%..2d\n' 0x1FE
111111110
$ printf '%#..2d\n' 0x1FE
2#111111110
```

In ksh93, `var=$(printf...)` doesn't fork a subshell so is as efficient as `bash`'s `printf -v`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the -v <variable assignment syntax>  NIIICE!!!  Thank you :)

Answer (score 16):

I would just simplify your script as:

```
printf "0x%X\n" $((0xA000 + 0x1000))
```

Comment: or `printf -v newbase "0x%X\n" $((0xA000 + 0x1000)); echo $newbase`

Comment: I like the one liner :)  Any way to get rid of the subshell (back ticks) for variable assignment?

Comment: Thers's no subshell. $((...)) is ugly addition syntax. With bash this is also possible: `$[0xA000 + 0x1000]`

Comment: @Cyrus It is possible, but it is a deprecated format.

Comment: I need the final result assigned to a variable though.  Hence the subshell with the printf wrapped in back ticks.  Still, this is the best yet :)

Answer (score 4):

In GNU or modern BSD `dc` you can do this like so:

```
echo A000 1000 | dc -e '16o16i?+p'
```

`16o` sets the output base.  `16i` sets the input base.  The `?` reads in a line from standard input, which in this case pushes two numbers onto the stack.  `+` adds them.  `p` prints the top of the stack (the answer).

Answer (score 1):

within bash it seems to be the good method.
you can also call tools like bc/dc (depending on your preferences) ...
echo 'obase=30; 123456' | bc

but I prefer the bash method 
In my point of view you 're doing well

Comment: Thank you :)  But that shell to printf is what makes me twitch.  Would be nice to not need to subshell out to get a formatted result.

Comment: @DavidAubin Note that ```printf``` is a bash built-in and probably much faster that any real command like ```bc```.

Answer (score 1):

The sum of `$hexNumA` and `$hexNumB` is:

```bsh
printf "%x\n" $((16#$hexNumA + 16#$hexNumB))
```

You can even add decimal to hex just as easily:

```bsh
printf "%x\n" $((16#$hexNum + $decNum))
```

courtesy: "[Convert Hexadecimal to Decimal in Bash](https://linuxhint.com/convert_hexadecimal_decimal_bash/)"