# Add two 256-bit hexadecimal numbers in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to add base 16 alphanumeric data using bash command. This works for numbers

```
total=$(( 55 + 60 ))
```

but not alphanumeric. Is there a simple bash command for adding alphanumeric data? I'm adding large alphanumeric data like this:

```
436389bdc34dd718c7959db8d6df16967f2b9895e515da45fb09136183a7a9e2
 +
1f0c45bbe9bc71a862f0d9672d056d2d741719a2b2d46ea6b269931d0b57674f
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `bash`, like all POSIX shells support adding hexadecimal numbers with

```
printf '%x\n' "$((0xfff + 0xaaa))"
```

(see: [How to add two hexadecimal numbers in a bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/415077))

That's limited to at best 64bit integers.

For numbers this big, you could use `bc`:

```
{
  echo obase=16
  echo ibase=16
  echo 436389bdc34dd718c7959db8d6df16967f2b9895e515da45fb09136183a7a9e2 +\
       1f0c45bbe9bc71a862f0d9672d056d2d741719a2b2d46ea6b269931d0b57674f |
   LC_ALL=C tr a-f A-F
} | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc
```

`BC_LINE_LENGTH=0` avoids the line wrapping with the GNU implementation of `bc`. With other implementations, you can pipe to `sed 'N;s/\\\n//'` instead.

Or GNU `awk` with `-M` (if built with arbitrary precision arithmetic support):

```
$ gawk -M 'BEGIN{printf "%x\n", \ 
  0x436389bdc34dd718c7959db8d6df16967f2b9895e515da45fb09136183a7a9e2 + \
  0x1f0c45bbe9bc71a862f0d9672d056d2d741719a2b2d46ea6b269931d0b57674f}'
626fcf79ad0a48c12a86772003e483c3f342b23897ea48ecad72a67e8eff1131%
```

Comment: This is what I need but its not adding correctly. Example: echo 5703c + 1 | LC_ALL=C tr a-f A-F | BC_LINE_LENGTH=120 bc                                              
But gives wrong answer:57040 should be 5703d Am I using the command wrong?

Comment: @RainyDay, you missed the `ibase` and `obase` part.

Comment: You're correct. The command works perfect in the script and the solution I needed.